# Почему возникает ошибка с установкой на ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache, yii2

вот gamer.lc.conf фаил

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName gamer.lc
        ServerAlias www.gamer.lc
        documentRoot /var/www/gamer.lc
        <Directory /var/www/gamer.lc >
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

подключено  и апач после этого перегружен вот htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if request begins with /admin remove admin and ad /backend/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

# other requests add /frontend/web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

# if frontend request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# if backend request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

выдает 500 ошибку вот лог

```
[Thu Jun 02 10:59:56.290501 2016] [core:alert] [pid 1397] [client 127.0.0.1:43767] /var/www/gamer.lc/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

объясните пожалуйста где туплю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache неоднозначно намекает, что Вы забыли включить модуль. В данном случае mod_rewrite. На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) есть описание, как это сделать.

Comment: вам вот это в моем сообщении ни чего не сказала sudo a2enmod rewrite  подключено и апач после этого перегружен

Comment: тогда у меня три варианта - 1) модуль все таки не включился - `apache2ctl -M`. 2) модуль включился, но `RewriteEngine` написано с ошибкой (например, через кириллическое е). 3) модуль от другого апача/нет доступа.

Comment: оказывается какого то апач не перегрузился помогло перезагруска компьютера спасибо большое